# Как убрать прозрачность букв в прозрачном боксе

Tags: html, css

Скажите пожалуйста, есть ли возможность убрать прозрачность у букв находящихся в прозрачном боксе[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
  <div class="bgr3" style="position:absolute;left:70%; width:30%; height:50vh; z-index:1;background:green; opacity:0.5;">


                <div class="text1" style="position:absolute; position: absolute; left:0%; top: 0%; opacity:1;  z-index:2;">
                    <strong>

                        Відгуки:<br>

                    </strong>

                </div>
                <br>
                <br>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <div>@item.Name  : "@item.Comment"</div>
                    <br>
                }

              
            </div>

            <a class="btn" style="position:absolute; position: absolute; height:15%; width:30%; left:70%; opacity:1; margin-bottom:0px;   top:85%; z-index:3; " href="@Url.Action("TextComments","Home")">Залишити коментарій</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

Просто надо дать прозрачность свeту заднего фона:

```
background: rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.5);
```

а не на общий `div`.

```html
<div class="bgr3" style="position:absolute;left:70%; width:30%; height:50vh; z-index:1;background: rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.5);">
  <div class="text1" style="position:absolute; position: absolute; left:0%; top: 0%; opacity:1;  z-index:2;">
    <strong>
      Відгуки:<br>
    </strong>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  @foreach (var item in Model)
  {
    <div>@item.Name  : "@item.Comment"</div>
    <br>
  }
</div>
 <a class="btn" style="position:absolute; position: absolute; height:15%; width:30%; left:70%; opacity:1; margin-bottom:0px;   top:85%; z-index:3; " href="@Url.Action("TextComments","Home")">Залишити коментарій</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

`opacity` делает прозрачным весь блок. Здать прозрачность фону можно указав цвет фона в `rgba`

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
}
.block {
  font-weight: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class='block'>ПРОЗРАЧНЫЙ БЛОК</div>
```